# Existence of periodic orbit of the ODE system $\dot{r}=r-r^3 \cos^2(\theta),\,\dot{\theta}= 1$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, dynamical-systems, stability-in-odes

> Consider the system of ODEs (in polar coordinates):
>   $$\dot{r}=r-r^3 \cos^2(\theta)$$
>   $$\dot{\theta}= 1$$

If we take $r_1 = \frac{1}{4}$ then $\dot{r}> 0$, and if we take $r_2 = \frac{3}{2}$ then $\dot{r}<0$, so $S:=\{r\in \mathbb{R}:r_1 \le r\le r_2\}$ should be a positively invariant set. Thus there should be a periodic orbit in $S$. But either I'm mistaken or not, and if not then what does the orbit look like?

Comment: If $r_2 = \frac{3}{2}$ when $\cos \theta$ is close enough to $\pi$, then $\dot r > 0$. One should anyway be able to solve this equation more or less explicitly using the variable change $u = r^{-2}$, but because of the above issue and the behavior of the function, I'd expect the solutions to below up in finite time.

Comment: I apologize. I've just made a correction. It should be $\cos^2(\theta)$, not $\cos(\theta)$.

Comment: Mathematica is actually capable of solving this system for generic $r(0)$, and upon inspecting the solution it seems that $r(0)=2/\sqrt{3}\approx 1.155$ indeed gives a periodic orbit. (I assume $\theta(0)=0$).

Comment: But if $\theta = 0$ then how is the angle changing to "draw" the orbit?

Comment: The angle is only zero at $t=0$. After that, it evolves according to $\dot{\theta}=1$ i.e. $\theta(t)=t$.

Comment: @Semiclassical: do you have software that can sketch this orbit? I think that the $\cos^2(\theta)$ term will make the orbit fluctuating, and it's not intuitively clear how it becomes a closed orbit.

Comment: As above, I'd use Mathematica (particularly since the present case is apparently solvable as I said before). But any software that lets you solve and plot ODEs should work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since $\theta' = 1$, we may as well treat $\theta$ as the independent variable. Changing (dependent) variables to $u := r^{-2}$ and rearranging gives
$$u' + 2 u = 2 \cos^2 \theta,$$
which is a linear, first-order ODE and can hence be solved by elementary techniques (including two integrations). The involved integrals can be evaluated in closed form and this leads to the solutions
$$u = \tfrac{1}{4}(2 + \sin 2 \theta + \cos 2 \theta + C e^{-2 \theta}) .$$
So, $u$ (and thus $r$) is periodic iff $C = 0$. Substituting shows that this holds only for the initial condition $u(0) = \tfrac{3}{4}$, or equivalently, $r(0) = u(0)^{-1 / 2} = \frac{2}{\sqrt{3}}$, which agrees with Semiclassical's comment.

This plot shows indicates the behavior for the three qualitative types of solutions; the blue plot is the unique periodic solution.

[image]

This plot was generated using the following Maple code:

```
dsolve(diff(r(theta), theta) = r(theta) - (r(theta)^3) * cos(theta)^2, r(theta));
op(2, %[2]);
[seq(eval(op(2, %), _C1 = C), C in {-3, 0, 3})];
plots:-polarplot(%, axiscoordinates = polar, coordinateview=[0..2, (-2 * Pi)..(2 * Pi)]);
```

Comment: Thank you. Then I guess I did this question well enough on the exam.

Comment: You're welcome, glad to hear it.